# How do I avoid network on main thread exception if I already use AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread, asynctaskloader

It seems to me I m not really calling URL,network operations **right from MainActivity**.

- I do call url.connect() in another class ProcessData
- I do use doInBackground()
- I do extend ProcessData class with AsyncTask

but the exception still occurs:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ProcessData test = new ProcessData();
        test.doInBackground("mysql") ;
    }

//separate file ProcessData.java
public class ProcessData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

public String createValidUrl(String s){
       .....//code in this method works fine
}
public String doInBackground(String ...params){
        String validUrl = createValidURL(params[0]);                   
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        URL url = new URL(validUrl);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();        
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");            
        urlConnection.connect();           

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            reader.close();

            return buffer.toString();
}
}
```

The network main thread exception still occurs, i read other SO posts.
I can wrap my http connection code into new thread, but I want to find exactly what is wrong

Comment: Post the stacktrace and the line to which it points.

Comment: @NiekHaarman, 03-28 16:35:45.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 16:35:45.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):  at com.android.okhttp.internl.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
03-28 16:35:45.086: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):  at com.example.kaban.it_ebooks2.ProcessData.doInBackground(ProcessData.java:130) basically, it is the line in doInbackground with inputstream = getinputstream()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call

```
test.execute();
```

instead of

```
test.doInBackground("mysql") ;
```

Comment: so execute() is IMPLICIT method that includes doInbackground followed by onPostExecute() ? is this how android works?

Comment: @ERJAN - Yes you have to call execute .It will take care of calling the onPreExecute(), then doInBackground() and then onPostExecute(). 
What is your first comment?Can you post in comments again.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call the `execute` method on an `AsyncTask` in order to run it in a background thread. What you're doing is calling `doInBackground` directly from the main thread.